# can anyone help me to connect rails 4 application to ms sql database(remote server) in windows system?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ruby-on-rails-4, database-connection

I succeeded in connecting to the remote database through ruby program by using dbi,ruby-odbc gems and by creating a system DNS for the remote ms sql server.

But I don't know how to connect using rails application, and I searched for the solution but I found it is needed to use tiny_tds but I am not sure it may solve the situation.

any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0):

In your database.yml file add your external db info ex:

```
# External Database for WW
external_database:
    <<: *default
    database: db_name
    username: username
    password: password
    host: www.host.com
```

Then create the appropriate model.rb files for the tables in the remote database, tell it to connect for the query, and add a custom table name if needed ex:

```
#app/models/product.rb

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    establish_connection :external_database
    self.table_name = "PRODUCT"

end
```

then bin/rails c and test it out